# How create only RooJavaBean File FILEVO_Roo_JavaBean.aj

Tags: java, spring, spring-roo

How create only File **FILEVO_Roo_JavaBean.aj** with Spring Roo shell 1.3.1.RC1??

This command generate many files:

```
roo> entity jpa --class com.model.vo.FileVO

Created SRC_MAIN_JAVA\...\vo\FileVO.java

Created SRC_MAIN_JAVA\...\vo\FileVO_Roo_Configurable.aj

Created SRC_MAIN_JAVA\...\vo\FileVO_Roo_ToString.aj

Created SRC_MAIN_JAVA\...\vo\FileVO_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord.aj

Created SRC_MAIN_JAVA\...\vo\FileVO_Roo_Jpa_Entity.aj

Created SRC_TEST_JAVA\...\vo\FileVODataOnDemand_Roo_DataOnDemand.aj

Created SRC_TEST_JAVA\...\vo\FileVOIntegrationTest_Roo_IntegrationTest.aj

~.model.vo.FileVO roo> Deleted SRC_TEST_JAVA\...\vo\FileVODataOnDemand_Roo_DataOnDemand.aj - empty

Deleted SRC_TEST_JAVA\...\vo\FileVOIntegrationTest_Roo_IntegrationTest.aj - empty
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you created the `.aj` files by hand? This files are managed by Spring roo and should not be modified (neither created) by user.

The command sequence to create the entity should be:

```
roo> entity jpa --class x.y.FileVO
Created SRC_MAIN_JAVA/x/y/FileVO.java
Created SRC_MAIN_JAVA/x/y/FileVO_Roo_Configurable.aj
Created SRC_MAIN_JAVA/x/y/FileVO_Roo_Jpa_Entity.aj
Created SRC_MAIN_JAVA/x/y/FileVO_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord.aj
Created SRC_MAIN_JAVA/x/y/FileVO_Roo_ToString.aj
~.FileVO roo> field string --fieldName name
Updated SRC_MAIN_JAVA/x/y/FileVO.java
Updated SRC_MAIN_JAVA/x/y/FileVO_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord.aj
Created SRC_MAIN_JAVA/x/y/FileVO_Roo_JavaBean.aj
~.FileVO roo> test integration 
Created SRC_TEST_JAVA/x/y
Created SRC_TEST_JAVA/x/y/FileVODataOnDemand.java
Created SRC_TEST_JAVA/x/y/FileVOIntegrationTest.java
Created SRC_TEST_JAVA/x/y/FileVODataOnDemand_Roo_DataOnDemand.aj
Created SRC_TEST_JAVA/x/y/FileVODataOnDemand_Roo_Configurable.aj
Created SRC_TEST_JAVA/x/y/FileVOIntegrationTest_Roo_Configurable.aj
Created     SRC_TEST_JAVA/x/y/FileVOIntegrationTest_Roo_IntegrationTest.aj
~.FileVO roo>
```

As you can see, `FileVO_Roo_JavaBean.aj` is created when is needed: after *FileVO* has the first field (this *.aj* generates getters and setters of class's properties, so, if there isn't properties in class it won't be generated).

Also I advise you to update to current Spring Roo version: 1.3.2

Good luck!